# Using user info from text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file called data.txt with a student numbers and names:

```
123, Bobbie Smith
456, Suzie Lan
789, Alex Palmer
```

What i'm trying to achieve is printing these information in sentences like this:

```
Bobbbie Smith has student number: 123
Suzie lan has student number: 456
Alex Palmer has student number: 789
```

So what I tried to do is putting every line on data.txt in a seperate list inside a list using:

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
studentInfo = file.readlines()
file.close()
lines = [[line] for line in studentInfo]

>>> print(lines)
[['123, Bobbie Smith\n'], ['456, Suzie Lan\n'], ['789, Alex Palmer']]
```

Is this to good direction or should I do this using a completely different way?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com, This is the place for posting code for code reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **don't** want to use `file` as a variable name, as it is a function. So you basically override it (thanks **@Mark Tolonen**).

You can slightly modify it and use context manager to read the file, and using `string.format` print the data in a readable fashion

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = [line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()]

for s in lines:
    print '{} has student number: {}'.format(s[1].strip(), s[0].strip())
```

Output:

```
Bobbie Smith has student number: 123
Suzie Lan has student number: 456
Alex Palmer has student number: 789
```

I'm striping new lines from line because `print` statement prints a new line by default for every iteration

Comment: `file` is not a keyword in Python, or you wouldn't be able to assign to it. It *is* a function in Python 2, but this question is tagged Python 3 where it is no longer a function.

Comment: I tried it but i get an error; list index out or range. I think this is because for instance the first line becomes: ['123, Bobbie Smith']. So using s[1] has no value.

Comment: @Tymo you're right, I've forgot to split the items. I've updated the answer with a working example

Comment: @Tymo if you found my answer helpful, please kindly consider upvoting it, thanks

Comment: @Vinny I did, but since I have less than 15 reputation is does not chance the  public displayed post score. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

use csv to avoid strip lines.

```
import csv

with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_f:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_f)

    for line in reader:
        print('{x[1]} has student number: {x[0]}'.format(x=line))
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is using the numpy library

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt("data.txt", dtype = str, delimiter = ',', unpack = True)
for (i,j) in zip(x,y):
print(j+" has student number: "+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways to achieve what you want using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

If you don't need to store the processed lines and just wanna print the output directly:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        try:
            age, name = re.findall(r'\s*(\d+),\s*(.*)', l)[0]
            print('{} has student number: {}'.format(name, age))
        except:
            pass
```

If you want to store the processed lines as a list of tuples, maybe something like this would do it:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = [v[0]
             for v in [re.findall(r'\s*(\d+),\s*(.*)', l) for l in f.readlines()] if v]
    for age, name in lines:
        print('{} has student number: {}'.format(name, age))
```